# can not use help in octave 3.8.1 on mac

Tags: macos, octave

when i enter:

```
>> help help
```

i get error message:

```
error: unable to open /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.1_1/share/octave/3.8.1/etc/macros.texi for reading  
error: called from:  
error:   /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.1_1/share/octave/3.8.1/m/help/__makeinfo__.m at line 103, column 5  
error:   /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.1_1/share/octave/3.8.1/m/help/help.m at line 99, column 22
```

How could i solve it? I'm using this on MacOS 10.10.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have the documentations installed !

Depending on how you have to installed `octave`, you have to specify somehow to install also the documentations.

If you need more help, then provide more info, on how `octave` has been installed.

---

If you have installed through `home-brew`, try to reinstall it with `with-docs` option i.e.

```
brew reinstall octave --with-docs
```

Comment: But does't octave's `help` work just like Matlab's? I would think that if you have the functions and M-files installed, then you'd have the `help` because this is just the comment block at the begging of each file. Am I missing something? However [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/1459#issuecomment-68543949) seems to say that you may have something. I guess they're not included the comment-only M-files for compiled code, maybe.

Comment: I installed octave by home-brew and i can't find how to install documentations on http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X.

Comment: Check the updated answer, aparently you've to reinstall with `with-docs` option

Comment: thx! I'm almost there except that at "make all" period,i met this:   ------        ==> make all
rm octave.df-t
rm octave-value/ov-bool-mat.df-t
mv operators/ops.cc-t operators/ops.cc
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2                 --------now i'm trying to figure it out by following instructions on https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting,  anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: by the way if you have any suggestions about my situation, please tell me!

Comment: Please update your question with to what to have reached and what problem you are facing now.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested quick-fix on git-hub ? `$ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/include/
$ sudo ln -s darwin/jni_md.h jni_md.h
$ sudo ln -s darwin/jawt_md.h jawt_md.h`

Comment: hi, i'm sorry haven't been here for a while, the prob is already fixed with your help, thank you sincerely!

Comment: glad to hear that its fixed, if my answer was a solution for you, you can mark it as accepted